# Android Alarm Clock with multiple alarms

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-alarms

I want to create a alarm clock with multiple alarms. I want to know how to create it using database and start the service. Suggest me some links or some tutorials which i can find helpful.

Right now i am using Pending Intent when one sets an alarm. Is it a viable solution to run multiple pending intents ? What if i want to have a feature of repeat alarm.

How can we design such a alarm clock ?

Comment: No downvote. For links and tutorials, you can use google. Try something and if you face any problem, then let us know here. Please read the [FAQs](http://stackoverflow.com/faq).

Comment: i have been searching for tutorial from past 3 days and couldnt find it. I want to create a multiple alarms and store it in database and trigger the alarm. All the tutorials speak only about single alarm using pending intents. How do i create multiple alarms and store it in database.

Comment: See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785702/android-set-multiple-alarms) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5549974/android-set-multiple-alarms-simultaneosuly). I found these with this [google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Creating+multiple+alarms+in+Android%3F&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb).

Answer (score 2):

Well a lot of similar questions have been asked on StackOverflow:

[Android Set Multiple Alarms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12785702/android-set-multiple-alarms)

[How to set more than one alarms at a time in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7252623/how-to-set-more-than-one-alarms-at-a-time-in-android)

[multiple alarms SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8317058/multiple-alarms-sqlite)

All have excellent answers, please go through them and ask us a more precise question here

Thank You